# rosdep error while urdf developing

Tags: urdf, rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello
I am very new to ROS and trying to develop a URDF for my own robot. First I wanted to learn the tutorials on the links below and then I would develop my own urdf.

but when i run this command given in the totorial. http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Building%20a%20Visual%20Robot%20Model%20with%20URDF%20from%20Scratch it gives error:
$rosdep install joint_state_publisher

ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required resources to answer your query
Missing resource joint_state_publisher

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/80321/rosdep-error-while-urdf-developing/) by [wafeeq](https://answers.ros.org/users/6400/wafeeq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-09-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wafeeq](https://answers.ros.org/users/6400/wafeeq/) on 2013-09-17**:
(http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Building%20a%20Visual%20Robot%20Model%20with%20URDF%20from%20Scratch)

**Comment by [wafeeq](https://answers.ros.org/users/6400/wafeeq/) on 2013-09-17**:
please find link of my tutorial in above comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The issue is that you need joint_state_publisher downloaded already. From the paragraph preceeding the command you ran:

```
In these tutorials, we’re going to rely on some tools and launch files from the urdf_tools package. Most notably, joint_state_publisher needs to be downloaded from the Washington University repository, linked to on the joint_state_publisher wiki page. All of the robot models mentioned in this tutorial can be found in the urdf_tutorial package.
```

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-09-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wafeeq](https://answers.ros.org/users/6400/wafeeq/) on 2013-09-17**:
Thanks for your reply. Actually I am new to ROS. I read this line but could not understand how to install joint_space_publicher.  Could you please guide me how to do that?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-09-17**:
You can find that in the 8th ROS tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/using_a_workspace  I suggest you go through all these tutorials before moving onto specific package tutorials: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials